# How to pass "Point" value to constructor

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, methods, point

public OneDimensionalShape(Point location, int dimension)

**Given above is the constructor but when I initialize the constructor from some RunnerClass like as bellow**

OneDimensionalShape myShape =  new OneDimensionalShape(1,0,5);

**It gives following error:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor OneDimensionalShape(int, int, int) is undefined

```
at com.introjava.chapter4.ShapeRunner.main(ShapeRunner.java:9)
```

Need your help on this please.

Comment: The error message says it all: you are passing three parameters to a method that only takes 2. It has nothing to do with constructors per se.

Answer (score -1):

The constructor `public OneDimensionalShape(Point location, int dimension)` has **two parameters**: `Point location` and `int dimension`.  Your code is calling the constructor with **3 parameters**: `1`, `0`, and `5`.  Given that your constructor has 2 parameters, where you are calling the constructor should also have 2 parameters.

Also, the first two parameters of your constructor are supposed to be a single **Point**, but instead they are **two integer values**.  You should try using `OneDimensionalShape myShape = new OneDimensionalShape(new Point(1,0),5);`

Also a point would be a 0 dimensional shape, since it has no width or height.  A one dimensionial shape would be a line, not a point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The reason of error was the way I was passing parameters to the constructor. I was not using new point(x,y), I was using (x, y, int). thank you very much.

Comment: that's what i was telling you to do.  If the answer helped you, please upvote it and accept the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark. :3